# Prevent HTML form action from being changed

Tags: javascript, html, forms, xss, action

I have a form on my page where users enter their credit card data. Is it possible in HTML to mark the form's action being constant to prevent malicious JavaScript from changing the form's action property? I can imagine an XSS attack which changes the form URL to make users posting their secret data to the attacker's site.

Is it possible? Or, is there a different feature in web browsers which prevents these kinds of attacks from happening?

Comment: How would the malicious JavaScript get into the form in the first place? Does the payment form allow user submitted content to be displayed (XSS)? That would be an unusual payment form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This kind of attack is possible, but this is the wrong way to prevent against it.  If a hacker can change the details of the form, they can just as easily send the secret data via an AJAX `GET` without submitting the form at all.  The correct way to prevent an XSS attack is to be sure to encode all untrusted content on the page such that a hacker doesn't have the ability to execute their own JavaScript in the first place.

---

More on encoding...

Sample code on StackOverflow is a great example of encoding.  Imagine what a mess it would be if every time someone posted some example JavaScript, it actually got executed in the browser.  E.g.,

`<script type="text/javascript">alert('foo');</script>`

Were it not for the fact that SO encoded the above snippet, you would have just seen an alert box.  This is of course a rather innocuous script - I could have coded some JavaScript that hijacked your session cookie and sent it to evil.com/hacked-sessions.  Fortunately, however, SO doesn't assume that everyone is well intentioned, and actually encodes the content.  If you were to view source, for example, you would see that SO has encoded my perfectly valid HTML and JavaScript into this:

`&lt;script type="text/javascript"&gt;alert('foo');&lt;/script&gt;`

So, rather than embedding actual `<` and `>` characters where I used them, they have been replaced with their HTML-encoded equivalents (`&lt;` and `&gt;`), which means that my code no longer represents a script tag.

Anyway, that's the general idea behind encoding.  For more info on *how* you should be encoding, that depends on what you're using server-side, but most all web frameworks include some sort of "out-of-the-box" HTML Encoding utility.  Your responsibility is to ensure that user-provided (or otherwise untrusted) content is *ALWAYS* encoded before being rendered.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'encode'?  Sounds great but I'm just not sure what technologies this would involve.

Comment: I know that the best way of preventing XSS attacks is encoding everything. But it's hard, you can always forget about a field. It's not so easy to send the secret data using AJAX because of the same origin policy. I can still see some advantages of having a feature like that.

Comment: @Michal - It's pretty easy to send data to a cross-origin server.  All you have to do is insert a script tag that points the script src=xxx" at some other server and puts the data as query parameters to the script tag URL.   This is how JSONP works, though JSONP is not needed here to merely send data to some other server.

Comment: @Michał - it's actually *very* easy to send secret data via AJAX using a `GET` request. It wouldn't be very "correct" in terms of RESTful semantics, but I don't think the hacker will lose much sleep on that point. It would be very ill-advised to try and prevent XSS the way that you requested. It's kind of like asking "How do I prevent my stolen car from being driven to Vegas?" Once you have that solved, you have to keep them from taking it to Seattle, and then LA, and so on. You're much better off simply learning how to properly lock the doors (i.e., prevent XSS entirely) :p

Comment: @jmar777 - You're right. I agree that preventing XSS is the best way to go. I'm not trying to say that the feature I proposed should be used to protect against that kind of attacks. What I had in mind is that this might be a nice feature to prevent that attack from happening when you accidentally forgot to encode the JS. Just a double-check.
BTW. Why do we need the same origin policy if it's still so easy to call other domain's URLs :)

Comment: @Michał - I can understand your motivation in wanting to provide some "insurance", in the event that you accidentally forgot to encode some content.  I'd just really want to impress upon you that any hacker that is capable of embedding an XSS attack in your page is also capable of getting around any client-side protections put in place. *(cont...)*

Comment: @Michał - regarding the same-origin policy, yes, it's absolutely needed. You have to remember that the same-origin policy isn't designed to protect data on the page that the user is *currently* on, but rather to protect data on pages that the user has *previously* been on. If it weren't for the same-origin policy, for example, you could create a script that performs secured actions against that user's banking site, as long as they still had a valid session. Provided that the bank is diligent about requiring POST's for secured actions, however, the user will be protected.

Comment: See the OWASP XSS Prevention Cheat Sheet for information on how to encode: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a different feature in web browsers which
>   prevents these kinds of attacks from happening?

Your concern has since been addressed by newer browser releases through the new [Content-Security-Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) header.

By configuring [script-src](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src), you can disallow inline javascript outright.  Note that this protection will not necessarily extend to users on older browsers (see [CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/#search=csp) ).

Allowing only white-labeled scripts will defeat most javascript XSS attacks, but may require significant modifications to your content.  Also, blocking inline javascript may be impractical if you are using a web frameworks that relies heavily on inline javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Nope nothing to really prevent it.

The only thing I would suggest to do is have some **server side** validation of any information coming to the server from a user form.

As the saying goes: *Never trust the user*

Comment: I think this question is more about protecting the user.

Comment: Protecting the user? from what?

Comment: Unwittingly. They can think they post the data to the same site, but the data is sent somewhere else.

Comment: @MichałFronczyk There is nothing I know that you can do to prevent that.