# Is there risk to having unsanitized user input display in a textarea?

Tags: html, security, xss, sanitization

I save two versions of user input in the following sequence:

1. Untrusted user enters raw markdown.
2. Raw markdown is stored in one table.
3. A copy of the raw markdown is converted into HTML.
4. HTML is sanitized and persisted, and is displayed upon request.
5. The raw markdown version is only displayed when users edit a entry; it's loaded into a textarea of a form.

Is there any risk in loading raw markdown (which could potentially contain unsafe HTML) into a textarea? It would never be displayed outside of a textarea.

I can't sanitize the markdown because it would result in inconsistencies between the markdown and HTML versions I'm saving.

FYI: I always sanitize SQL, regardless of what I'm saving to the DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends how you're "loading" it into the `textarea`.  If you're doing it server-side through simple string concatenation, e.g. in php,

```
$output = '<textarea>' + $markdown + '</textarea>';
```

...then there is absolutely a risk, because that markdown could very easily close out the `textarea` and embed whatever else it wants.  If you're using some sort of a component framework (e.g., ASP.NET), then you should be protected as long as you use a safe API method, such as `MyTextArea.Value = markdown;`.

If you're doing it client-side, it also depends on how you're doing this.  You would be safe if you used something like jQuery's `.val()` setter, but could still expose yourself to XSS vulnerabilities through other approaches.

In short, the general answer is yes, depending on how you're actually creating and populating the `textarea`.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to sanitize it there, just take care of correctly escaping HTML special characters such as < and >.

For instance, Stackoverflow allows you to post HTML code in your posts, it does not remove anything. This is achieved by encoding, not sanitizing.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "this is achieved by encoding, not sanitizing"? A small example would be really helpful.

Comment: I just recently posted an answer that involved HTML encoding - maybe it'll be useful as a brief explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475943/prevent-html-form-action-from-being-changed/7476001#7476001

Comment: @jmar777, I saw that. Great explanation. Thanks. I should probably just encode everything. The problem arises though when there are certain tags that I don't want to encode. Such as <b> and <i>...

Answer (score 0):

Are you at least doing SQL sanitation? When you INSERT or UPDATE the data, are you using some type of DAO that escapes the SQL or, if using Java, using a Prepared Statement where you set the arguments?

You must **always** sanitize things before they go into the DB. Otherwise people could add a stray

```
'); --Malicious procedure here.
```

..into a request.

There are some security risks to leaving unsanitized input in the text box; mainly if the user is infected with something that's injecting Javascript, it will show up for him or her each time.

Why even save that? Then you're giving your user a totally inconsistent view from what they enter to what is displayed? They won't match up. It's best to clean the input so when they user views it again he or she *can clearly see* that the offending HTML was removed for security.

Comment: I do sanitize all my SQL statements. I definitely need to safe a raw version. This allows my users to see exactly what they put into the textarea. I want to keep them away from the HTML unless they choose to use HTML... a la StackOverFlow. When you edit a post, they load a raw markdown version, not the cooked HTML version we see on a post page.