# How to change text based on a string in the address bar?

Tags: jquery

I am using the code below to add a `select` class on the `a` which has an `id` that matches a string in the address bar. But I also need to be abe to change the text of a `dropdown-toggle` to match the same string.

```
var string = document.location.href.split('=')[1];

if ($('li a[id^="filter-"][id*="' + string + '"]').length){
   $('li a[id^="filter-"][id*="' + string + '"]').addClass('selected');
}

var text = $("li a.selected").html();
var htmlText = text + ' <span class="caret"></span>';
$('.dropdown-toggle').html(htmlText);
```

The above code changes the text of `.dropdown-toggle` to:

```
undefined
```

Instead it should change it to

`Ogilvy`

The full URl is:

```
http://www.example.com/xchanges/#comboFilters%5BAgencies%5D=.Ogilvy&comboFilters%5BClients%5D=.Vodafone
```

html

```
<ul id="filters" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                  <li class="option-combo dropdown  Agency">
                        <a class="btn btn-default btn-lg dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-expanded="false">.Ogilvy&amp;comboFilters%5BClients%5D <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="filter option-set dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1" data-filter-group="Agencies">
                    <li><a class="btn btn-default btn-lg" href="#" data-filter-value="">All agencies</a></li>
                                              <li><a id="filter-TBWA" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" href="#filter-agency-TBWA" data-filter-value=".TBWA">TBWA</a></li>
                                              <li><a id="filter-Ogilvy" class="btn btn-default btn-lg selected" href="#filter-agency-Ogilvy" data-filter-value=".Ogilvy">Ogilvy</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                  </li>

                  <li class="option-combo dropdown  Client">
                        <a class="btn btn-default btn-lg dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-expanded="false">.Ogilvy&amp;comboFilters%5BClients%5D <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="filter option-set dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2" data-filter-group="Clients">
                     <li><a class="btn btn-default btn-lg" ref="#" data-filter-value="">All clients</a></li>
                                              <li><a id="filter-Sky" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" href="#filter-client-Sky" data-filter-value=".Sky">Sky</a></li>
                                              <li><a id="filter-Vodafone" class="btn btn-default btn-lg selected" href="#filter-client-Vodafone" data-filter-value=".Vodafone">Vodafone</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                  </li>

                  <li class="option-combo dropdown  Year">
                        <a class="btn btn-default btn-lg dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-expanded="false">.Ogilvy&amp;comboFilters%5BClients%5D <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="filter option-set dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2" data-filter-group="Years">
                    <li><a class="btn btn-default btn-lg" ref="#" data-filter-value="">All years</a></li>
                                              <li><a id="filter-y2013" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" href="#filter-year-y2013" data-filter-value=".y2013">2013</a></li>
                                              <li><a id="filter-y2014" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" href="#filter-year-y2014" data-filter-value=".y2014">2014</a></li>
                                              <li><a id="filter-y2012" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" href="#filter-year-y2012" data-filter-value=".y2012">2012</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                  </li>
            <li><button class="btn btn-default btn-lg no-bkg" id="open-button">About</button></li>
                </ul>
```

Comment: From where I see it your code will be prone to XSS attacks. Displaying code base on unsanitized user input might indeed lead to  different kinds of abuse...

Comment: what code am I displaying based on unsanitized user input?

Comment: I am populating it via client side not server side, it should be ok no?

Comment: You're taking string from the querystring and injecting it right away in your HTML through the 3 first lines of the code you provide. So basically it would be possible to generate a malicious URL pointing to your website but executing remotely hosted malicious javascript. Or I missed something, but I'm quite sure of what I say.

Comment: i thought that was something to do with server side tho, not client

Comment: so basically i should use special characters right? as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475943/prevent-html-form-action-from-being-changed/7476001#7476001

Comment: Indeed... and be anyway really carefull (and if possible avoid it). There might actually be much safer way to do what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly use `document.location.hash` instead of `href` so you are only working with `#comboFilters%5BAgencies%5D=.Ogilvy&comboFilters%5BClients%5D=.Vodafone` not the whole thing.

Then you need to split this by `&` into parts. The for each part split *that* by `=` and store that in a object. One that is done you just need to grab the part you want:

```js
var hash = document.location.hash;
// hard code a hash value here for the purposes of demonstrating the code
hash =  '#comboFilters%5BAgencies%5D=.Ogilvy&comboFilters%5BClients%5D=.Vodafone';

// create an object to act like a dictionary to store each value indexed by its key
var partDic = {};

// remove the leading "#" and split into parts
var parts = hash.substring(1).split('&');

// If you just want the first value, whatever it is, use this.
// But be aware it's a URL so can be set to anything in any order, so this makes little sense
// var string = parts[0].split('=')[1];

// build the dictionary from each part
$.each(parts, function(i, v) {
  // do the "=" split now
  var arr = v.split("=");

  // decode to turn "%5B" back into "[" etc
  var key = decodeURIComponent(arr[0]);
  var value = decodeURIComponent(arr[1]);

  // store in our "dictionary" object
  partDic[key] = value;
});

// check the part we want is in the URL
if(partDic["comboFilters[Agencies]"]) {
  // now just grab the part we want, and remove the leading "."
  var string = partDic["comboFilters[Agencies]"].substring(1);
  $('div').html(string);
}
else {
  $('div').html("Agency filter not set");
}

// ... continue as before
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Comment: yeah but this assumes you already know the full address right? My address is generated by history bbq dynamically

Comment: @rob.m What do you mean this assumes you know the full address? I had to hard-code the value into the snippet or it wouldn't run correctly, but in your actual script you just need `var hash = document.location.hash`.

Comment: sorry, I meant in the bottom it says var string = partDic["comboFilters[Agencies]"].substring(1); but that Agency could be Client or Year too as per my set of uls. Also the text should grab it from the a with class "selected". Which is a class I am adding in my first set of code as you can see